# GCP KMS API max size supported text

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to use the symmetric key to encrypt and decrypt the text. I will like to know what is the maximum size of user entered text (how many characters) that can be encrypted and decrypted with the GCP symmetric keys.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you are going to use "cryptoKeys.encrypt" method...

According to [Method: cryptoKeys.encrypt documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys/encrypt) the limit is 64Kb (in bytes).

In my personal experinece (cloud function developed in Go) - I got exceptions with a message: "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 1048576 bytes"

To overcome that limitation I used another Google library - [Tink - A multi-language, cross-platform library that provides cryptographic APIs that are secure, easy to use correctly, and hard(er) to misuse.](https://github.com/google/tink)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the limitation is based on the type of key used: symmetric or asymmetric or if it is independent of it ?

Comment: According to [Encrypting and decrypting data with an asymmetric key](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt-rsa): "The plaintext data you want to encrypt must not be larger than 64 KiB (65,536 bytes)."

Comment: Thanks al-dann. Actually I am trying to use the symmetric key and want to check if there is any documentation on the symmetric keys.